# Android FloatingActionButton speed dial alternative

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button, bottom-sheet

I'm using `FloatingActionButton` with speed dial style in my app, in order to create different items. The problem is number of items is exceeding the allowed number in Material Design.

According to [Material Design guidelines](https://material.io/design/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#types-of-transitions):

> When pressed, a FAB can display three to six related actions in the
>   form of a speed dial. This transition can occur in one of the
>   following ways:
>
> - Upon press, the FAB can emit related actions.
> - Upon press, the FAB can transform into a menu containing related       actions (Android only).

And so:

> If more than six actions are needed, something other than a FAB should
>   be used to present them.

But I can't find any official alternative for this case that there are more primary actions. I've found Google Drive app that uses `FloatingActionButton` in conjunction with modal `BottomSheet` to show more primary actions:

[image]

But I don't know is it a good design? Or is there any other material solution?